# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException - Unable to hit the verify button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing script for verify mobile number and when i hit on verify mobile button element, the following error is showing.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (285.5, 59.600006103515625). Other element would receive the
>   click:  Command duration or
>   timeout: 78 milliseconds

I have written this code to verify OTP with different condition.

```
// Verify OTP should not accept more than 6 characters value
        String otp = Constants.WRONG_OTP;       
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys(Constants.MOBILE_NUMBER);
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_verify")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement otp1_value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@id='otp']"));
        otp1_value.sendKeys(Constants.WRONG_OTP);
        if(otp.length()>6){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@type='submit']")).click();
            System.out.println("Incorrect otp");
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@type='button']")).click();
        // verify message after entering correct OTP
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys("1231231232");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form_register']//*[@type='button']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement otp_value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@id='otp']"));
        otp_value.sendKeys(Constants.MOBILE_OTP);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@type='submit']")).click();
        String otp_success_msg = driver.findElement(By.className("opt_success")).getText();
        System.out.println(otp_success_msg);
        WebElement otp_reset = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verifyOTP_register']//*[@id='otp']"));
        otp_reset.clear();
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox browser

Comment: can you share the url of the application or post a `HTML` snippet?

Comment: http://talentrack.in/register

Comment: which browser version and selenium version are you using?

Comment: selenium version : 2.53 & browser version : 45.0.2

Comment: The same code that i have written ? actually i am checking two different condition as mentioned in my code, for first condition it is working for me but for second condition it is not working. Can you verify and run my code please?

Comment: lets have a discussion join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110304/36871866

Comment: both the conditions are working for me...

Comment: Ok, let me try at my end